# How to get current text color in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, text

I am working off of a psd mockup to put together a page.

I have been using the eyedropper tool to get text colors, but I suspect there's a better way to do this, since I believe the eyedropper might sometimes be picking up anti-aliasing -- that is to say, it's perhaps picking up a color other than the "official" color used on the text.

Anyone have a workflow that works for this scenario? I'd love to be able to help the next person out on this, even if I'm not the one to benefit immmediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Text Tool and click on the Text, you will see Color option in the "option Menu" of Photoshop, click and open it to get the color;
See the screenshot below:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can always see the original colors on the Option bar. Just select the text tool and choose the text layer you need.

Comment: Thanks for contributing! This answer could be improved by including a screenshot(s) and otherwise providing more detail. Right now it is lacking